# Merge JSON values into a variable or string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, merge, jsonp

I JSON nodes with the same title, but different latitude and longitude values in each node. I need to check for the same title value, but then merge together the latitude and longitude values into a url for a map API. I need it to be in this order latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude, etc... I just don't know what to do at this point. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

JS VAR

```
<img class="detail_map" src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getplacemap?size=320,240&zoom=15&location=' + data.nodes.Latitude + ',' + data.nodes.Longitude + '&imagetype=jpeg&showicon=blue-1">
```

JSON Object

```
var data = fl({
"nodes":[
    {"node":{
        "title":"180","Address":"555 Market St. San Francisco, CA United States See map: Google Maps","
        Latitude":"37.789952","
        Longitude":"-122.400158"}},
    {"node":{
        "title":"180","Address":"Epic Roasthouse (399 Embarcadero) San Francisco, CA United States See map: Google Maps","
        Latitude":"37.797677","
        Longitude":"-122.394339"}},
    {"node":{
        "title":"180","Address":"Mason &amp; California Streets (Nob Hill) San Francisco, CA United States See map: Google Maps","
        Latitude":"37.791556","
        Longitude":"-122.410766"}},
    {"node":{
        "title":"180","Address":"Justin Herman Plaza San Francisco, CA United States See map: Google Maps","
        Latitude":"37.774930","
        Longitude":"-122.419416"}},
    {"node":{
        "title":"180","Address":"200 block Market Street San Francisco, CA United States See map: Google Maps","
        Latitude":"37.793133","
        Longitude":"-122.396560"}} 
]});
```

});

Comment: What does merge together latitude and longitude values into the url mean?

Comment: What happens when the `node`s get merged? Each `node` contains different data besides `title`.

Comment: When the nodes get merged it just puts all the information in the same value. I can't have all the latitudes and longitudes in one value. I need latitudes and longitudes following each other. lat,long,lat,long. I can't have lat,lat,lat,lat or long,long,long,long

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function for merge two objects, the different properties will be replaced.

Example:

```
var newData = $.extend(data1, data2);
// Assuming data1, data2 are objects;
```

If you need convert string JSON to object, use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do something like this where var url_part is used to replace "data.nodes.Latitude + ',' + data.nodes.Longitude" from the img src:

```
var url_part = '';
$.each(data.nodes, function(key,val){
    url_part += val.node.Latitude+","+val.node.Longitude+",";
});
```

but before useding url_part, you need to remove the last coma...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `$.map()`. Compare the object's node.title value, and then from there return the string as you would expect. When you're done, join the array on `,`.

```
var locs = $.map(fl.nodes, function(obj,i){
    return obj.node.title == '180' ? 'latitude='+obj.node.Latitude+'&longitude='+obj.node.Longitude : '';
}).join(',');
```

would return `lat1,long1,lat2,long2,lat3,long3,lat4,long4,lat5,long5`

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBsEw/)

**Edit 1**

Added support for dynamic titles.

```
function getNodesByTitle(title){
    return $.map(fl.nodes, function(obj,i){
        return obj.node.title == title ? 'latitude='+obj.node.Latitude+'&longitude='+obj.node.Longitude : '';
    }).join(',');
}
```

In theoretical practice:

```
var locString = getNodesByTitle('your title here');
```

Comment: Awesome. This would work, but what if there more nodes with different titles?

Comment: @Justin then make it a function. pass in the node title, and change `'180'` to whatever you want.

Comment: Hmm yeah. I already had it in function getting the title passed to it, but all it would return to me is just commas (,,,,,,,). Maybe I need to explain better what I am doing?

Comment: Show me what the string needs to look like. I'll show you how to do it. As far as for only getting commas; I don't know. It should at least return `undefined`. Also, for example, [here's the string at workin this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuPPD/)

Comment: I am parsing the JSON to check for the title onclick and then merge all the values and display them. This is what I have working for the address value. I just need what your JS is doing to work on click. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbpyrojust/HbNW4/)

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a function to merge addresses and latitude and longitude. Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbpyrojust/HbNW4/16/) to see it in action.

```
function fl(data){
//data = JSON.parse(data);
//Array to hold movie titles   
var movieTitles = []; 
//Assign Movies to to movies Array and ensure unique
for (var i=0; i < data.nodes.length; i++)
{
    //Look for the current title in the movieTitles array
    var movieIndex = movieTitles.indexOf(data.nodes[i].node.title);
    if (movieIndex>-1) //If the title already exists
    {
        //Merge all the properties you want here
        movies[movieIndex].Address += ", " + data.nodes[i].node.Address;
        if(!movies[movieIndex].Coords) movies[movieIndex].Coords = [];
        movies[movieIndex].Coords.push(
            data.nodes[i].node.Latitude + "," + data.nodes[i].node.Longitude
        );
    }
    else
    {
        //var address = movies[movieIndex].Address; movies[movieIndex].Address = address.replace(/^\s*/,'');
        //Add movie to movies array
        movies.push(data.nodes[i].node);
        //Add movie title to movieTitles array
        movieTitles.push(data.nodes[i].node.title);

    }
}

displayLinks(); //Load all the links
//showCast(0); //Display details for first item
```

}
//});